# Display highmaps map on React

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, highcharts

Hello I am creating a react interface where when a user access the website,  a pop-up appears asking the user to accept permissions to access user location. After a user accepts using the location, a marker would be displayed with a marker on location of user. I am using highmaps and here is the code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import HighchartsMap from 'highcharts/modules/map';
import mapData from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json';

HighchartsMap(Highcharts);

const MapChart = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        setLocation({
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lon: position.coords.longitude
        });
      });
    }
  }, []);

  const options = {
    chart: {
      map: 'countries/us/us-all'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Your Location'
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'mappoint',
      name: 'Your Location',
      data: location ? [{ lat: location.lat, lon: location.lon }] : []
    }]
  };

  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={Highcharts}
      options={options}
      constructorType={'mapChart'}
    />
  );
};

export default MapChart;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import MapChart from './MapChart';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MapChart />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I run the code I get an empty interface, there is no map at all, it shows this

[image]

Now looking at the console, I find this error

```
xhr.js:187 
 GET http://localhost:8000/village_pred/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js:187
xhrAdapter  @   xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js:53
request @   Axios.js:108
Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js:129
wrap    @   bind.js:9
(anonymous) @   Navbar.jsx:29
commitHookEffectListMount   @   react-dom.development.js:23150
invokePassiveEffectMountInDEV   @   react-dom.development.js:25154
invokeEffectsInDev  @   react-dom.development.js:27351
commitDoubleInvokeEffectsInDEV  @   react-dom.development.js:27330
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js:27056
flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop    @   scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork   @   scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline    @   scheduler.development.js:533
```

How can I fix this, so that to see the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more series with `map` type:

```
  const options = {
    title: {
      text: "Your Location"
    },
    series: [
      {
        type: "map",
        mapData
      },
      {
        type: "mappoint",
        name: "Your Location",
        data: location ? [{ lat: location.lat, lon: location.lon }] : []
      }
    ]
  };
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-zn6o2b?file=/demo.jsx

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-series